# Unable to download .exe from SharePoint 2013 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, development, document-library

We have a web application which allow users to download documents from SharePoint. Recently we have received a requirement to enable downloading .exe file. But on `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` I am getting following error. Moreover, while retrieving file extension is coming as `aspx` instead of `.exe`.

```
FileUrl: http://domainname/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=14394
```

**Error**

`Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.`

Can anyone please suggest me how we can enable users to download .exe files directly using web application.

Comment: Please post relevant code. Also the FileURL is not correct. The url should be something like `http://domainname/Shared Documents\file.exe`

Comment: Are you able to download normal file like office documents (doc, docx, etc.)?

Comment: yes, I can download documents, zip files etc.

Comment: If you try to download the exe file from the library, is it allowing to do that?

Comment: Yes, it allows to download through SP. but in code I am getting `Access denied.` error. I think something is wrong with the url it is returing.

Comment: Scorpion: One download click you can try to print the URL its trying to download. I think that will give you the answer.

Comment: its trying to download wrong Url. `http://domainname/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=14394`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20185/discussion-between-scorpion-and-amal-hashim).

Comment: Just searched in Doc library in SP. exe behaves little different from other document. .pdf or word documents have url ending with their extensions. But exe is loaded in Display form. which is a different behaviour. Looks like error is on SP side not in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Answer actually sorted my Problem. Thanks to [@daver306](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4540/daver306)

[Make SharePoint search results link to document instead of DispForm.aspx with no iFilter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/make-sharepoint-search-results-link-to-document-instead-of-dispform-aspx-with-no)